# I am confused what ffmpeg file is in android

Tags: android

Please can anyone tell me the usages of ffmpeg file in android. Though I tried to browse but none of them satisfied me.

Comment: Read this https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/https-medium-com-wolox-driving-innovation-the-power-of-ffmpeg-on-android-ef6e0c01d59f

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is library,it will used to decode and encode audio,video file , if you are streaming a video from your android application it will be used.